# @EJB lookup as parameter instead of hard coded

Tags: jakarta-ee, jndi, lookup, ejb-3.1

I have inherited a Java EE web app with a group of JSF that made use of EJB injection for accessing a `@Remote` interface:

```
@EJB(lookup = "java:global/myapp-business/myapp-services/CustomerFacadeBean")
```

It works, but as I am reviewing the application for the deployment guys I would like to make this as a parameter.

I suppose there must be a good reason for the developer to have used only `lookup` so as a first tentative I am willing to replicate the same scenario.

But, I would like to have opinion to make this injection as much 'portable' and 'configurable' as possible. If I am not wrong in the old days of Ejb 2 there were the ejb-ref in the web.xml.

Answer (score 1):

The `@EJB` declares an EJB references, and application servers are required to support configurable bindings for EJB references at deployment time.  The `lookup` attribute of the annotation allows the developer to specify a default binding unless the deployer overrides it.  You will need to consult your application server documentation to determine how to configure this binding.

Note, `@EJB` annotation has a `name` attribute, which is what the deployer must configure.  If the name attribute is not supplied, then it defaults to `<class>/<member>`.  For example, if the class is `test.MyBean` and the field is `myEjb`, then the EJB reference name will be `test.MyBean/myEjb`.

Answer (score 0):

From J2EE 6+ lookup attribute is required for JNDI lookup to resolve the target. The other ways of JNDI lookups used in older versions are like for example :                                                                           @EJB(name="myBean") creates a reference java:comp/env/myBean in component namespace.
And if name is not specified in the attribute then it creates a reference as java:comp/env/com.example.MyClass/myField